# Get JSON values and print out using PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm loading in a javascript file (which has a json structure) and then I want to echo out in PHP a for loop of each "title" key values.

Can anyone help me get through this? I'm a beginner at this. I can't seem to find or learn how to do this. Thanks!

**Here is what I have....**

```
$string = file_get_contents("file.js");
$json_a = json_decode($string, true);
echo  $json_a['data'] .....
```

**Here is my javascript json file**

```
// Json Object

var data = [{
    tags: [{
            name: 'a',
            content: '<img src="1.jpg">',
            cssanimate: 'fadeIn',
            attr: {
                href: '#',
                title: 'title1'
            }
        }]
},{
    tags: [{
            name: 'a',
            content: '<img src="2.jpg">',
            cssanimate: 'flipInY',
            attr: {
                href: '#',
                title: 'title2'
            }
        }]
},{
    tags: [{
            name: 'a',
            content: '<img src="3.jpg">',
            cssanimate: 'bounce',
            attr: {
                href: '#',
                title: 'title3'
            }
        }]
}


];

// Call Slider function
$(window).load(function () {
  $('#slideshow-slider').jSonSlider({
    'loadallslides': false,
    'auto': [true, '14000'],
    'nextprev': false,
    'circular': true,
    'pagi': false,
    'data': data
  });
});
```

Comment: You could do a foreach loop on $json_a['data']

Comment: `json_decode()` doesn't decode Javascript, it decodes JSON. You need to have just pure JSON in the file you're loading.

Comment: @AlexHowansky - Thank you for letting me that know!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can keep JSON in a separate .json file and try using the same PHP code (with changed file name inside file_get_contents()).

Your code is not working because you are storing JSON object on a JavaScript variable and slider code as well.

Just to point out JavaScript and PHP are different client side and server side script languages respectively and can not use each other's variables etc.

Comment: Vivek Srivastava - Thank you for the feedback!